# Multiple (independent) circuits on the same PCB in Multisim/Ultiboard

Tags: pcb-design, multisim, ultiboard

I have designed and simulated a few circuits on Multisim. Usually, I order a PCB for the layout of each circuit independently. However, it is cost-effective to put multiple circuits on the same board (the cost of an additional circuit on the same board is less than the cost of a new board with the additional circuit).

How does one put together multiple independent layouts from different circuits on the same PCB in Ultiboard? Several issues arise if one simply draws all the circuits in one schematic and puts them together on the same board -- for example ground and power planes get shared, and I do not want this.

Comment: Well, you could always define your own planes as ground and power

Comment: Right, but then the plane defined as ground, for example, would fill up the entire board including regions of other circuits.

Comment: I mean define independent ground planes, i.e. ground0, ground1, ground2...

Comment: But then you would need as many planes as grounds. My question is basically this exact issue - is there a way to isolate each circuit so that I can have one ground plane pour and then no copper and then another ground plane pour, and so on, all on the same plane?

Comment: Perhaps a bit more clarification I'd necessary. Basically, imagine a board design for a circuit, and then another completely different one. How would you put them on the same board without having them share traces or planes?

Comment: I see.  Got me there.

Comment: I think you are looking for "Panelisation", but my last experience with Ultiboard is in 1998, and back then boards were expensive enough to have the fab do that, so I'm afraid I can't help you do that with Ultiboard. Do they even still make Ultiboard? :-P

Comment: A fundamental property of a net is that it expects all points on the net to connect to every other. If you don't want that, you should use separate nets, such as in this situation. Why is it so important to you they all be part of the same 'ground' net, even though they're physically disconnected?

Comment: I would place a track loop on each plane to prevent traces from crossing.  In a similar question relating to a component it was sugegsted to make this into the part outline.  You could have a gap too small for a trace to enter or exit but still have routes inside.

Comment: I agree with Nick, use different nets if you don't want the signals to be connected. Of course you'll have to define multiple ground planes then, but that shouldn't be an issue. I don't see how your approach would work together e.g. with DRC. But if you really want to go that way you could probably use keep-out regions.